# Trying to Push to Live Nginx Ubuntu Server Using Git

Tags: git, ubuntu, nginx

I have set up my git on my liveserver on Ubuntu Nginx Server but anytime i try to push it gives this error `[remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please show the full text of the error.

Comment: @phd I am sure you do not expect me to post my ssh link right? ```Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 884 bytes | 221.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory
To ```

Comment: ssh link — no, just that full text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remote+unpack+failed%3A+unable+to+create+temporary+object+directory